# QML: How can I access the id of an Item outside of repeater?

Tags: repeater, qml

I'm new to QML and I encounter a problem when I try to access an element from inside a repeater.

I have a repeater which generates rectangles with a mouse area each. Clicking the mouse-area should change the color of the background window *root* defined before, but when clicked I only get: "ReferenceError: root is not defined". If I create a rectangle with mouse-area outside of the repeater then it works. So how can I access elements outside of the repeater with a mouse-area inside the repeater? Thank you for any help. I'm really stuck with this problem right now.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window
id: root
visible: true
width: 600; height: 600
color: "black"
{
Grid
{
    columns: 3
    spacing: 20
    x: 20
    y: 20
    Repeater{
        id: repeater1
        model: 3
        Rectangle {
            color: "White"; width: 100; height: 100;
            radius: 10
            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked:
                {
                    root.color="white"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my windows emulator, And I couldn't even run it right; it just showed me a white blank page. Maybe it's because I am not using QQuickWindow in my main.cpp.

To run it on my emulator, I changed your Window element to Rectangle and it perfectly works fine. When I click a button, the background color gets changed to white.

Comment: If you must use Window element, can you post your main.cpp?

Answer (score -2):

First import these two headers

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
```

Second where is the curly braces **{}** of your window item **root**

Comment: I added it now. I had it in my source code anyway and adjusted it now here in the question. The imports and curly braces are not related to the problem though. If you can help me I would be glad. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I built a QT Quick UI from your code and it works just fine for me. Try to test it as a user interface first to see if it works for you or not.